# Identification of Particular Status which Occurred only once in excel

Tags: google-sheets

I have a data set scenario where I want to find the user has picked the call only once ,irrespective of the Time against each Order Id, it does not matter to me, when the user has picked the call once, either first time only, second time only or Nth time
only.

If user has picked  Call only once then I want to consider "Yes" against that Order No. Other wise "No".
It can be possible that call attempts can be one or more than one against that Order No.

Note : ex :Order No: 44551 ,  only one attempt is made and the Status is Responsive, then against this order No.  "No" should be there as only one attempt is made and which is Responsive.

Similarly Order No : 3456789, only one attempt is made and the Status is Not Responsive, then against this order No.  "Yes" should be there as only one attempt is made and which is  Not Responsive.

[Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSXmX.png)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Is it for google sheets or excel?

Comment: it is for Google sheets

Comment: Can you share a public copy of the sheet? Even if it is with random data?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`COUNTIFS` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) to check the number of rows meeting various criteria (criteria being Order No. , whether it's responsive, which user made the attempt etc).
Then, either output the results to a new column using
`=IF(COUNTIFS(...)=1, "Yes", "No")` or put them in a conditional formatting rule with the formula `=COUNTIFS(...)=1` to highlight relevant rows.

Comment: =IF(COUNTIFS(...)=1, "Yes", "No"), this is working only in  the conditions where attempt is made only once and status is Unresponsive, could you pls help me with working example

Comment: @Grig Please copy in the formula that you have tried, without the dots

Comment: Also note that this answer was written for excel not Google sheets, I'm not 100% sure on the compatibility

Comment: IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,A:A,$W:$W,"Unresponsive")=1, "Yes", "No"))    (A Column as OrderNo and W column has Status)

Comment: Ok - I can see what's wrong with that formula, it needs to only check one row at a time. So, for row 2 it would be `=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,A:A,$W:$W,"Unresponsive")=1, "Yes", "No")) ` - try copying that into row 2 of your sheet and then copy downwards and see what difference that makes?